# how to set whole app background color in flutter

Tags: flutter

is there a way to set whole app backgorundcolor in flutter. For example i want to use white background on all screens. so the first thing i do is manually setting background color to all screens. But i think its overkill. and i am looking for the a shortcut to achieve it.

i have tried below code but couldn't get achieve what i wanted.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<SplashBloc>(
      bloc: splashBloc,
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: new ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white),
        home: Splash(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You've already quite achieved this. You just need to do this in your `main.dart` file. Is the code above from your `main.dart` file?

Comment: @ByteMe yes. its in main.dart

Comment: delete the `backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(254, 248, 248, 1),` and the whole app will follow the app background color that you've set  in the `ThemeData`

Comment: not worked. i have updated the code block. @ByteMe

Comment: Quick question, does your code return a `Scaffold` widget for every page in your app?

Comment: yes. all widget returns scaffold. but i think its not necessary @ByteMe

Answer (score 3):

In main.dart, use,

```
MaterialApp(
theme: ThemeData(
scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white),
),
```

This will change the background color of the entire app provided you are returning Scaffold in the build Widget.

Answer (score -1):

You use use the theme in your MaterialApp Widget to set up the theme colors for your entire app like so:

```
MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
          primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(254, 248, 248, 1),
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
            color: <color_of_choice>,
          ),
        ),
```

Your backgroundColor will assume the primaryColor above.

Read all about it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html).

Comment: its not working. i have updated the code block that i shared in question

Comment: tried using backgroundColor instead of ScaffoldBackgroundColor?